Return Single record from JSON Data file in Blazor WASM
New to Blazor and I am migrating an old site to help learn.
This is a classic list all items, click Item to view details scenario
I have done the list all items in 1 page "Portfolio" using the following (which works perfect)
@code {
    private artWork[]? artWorks;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
       
            artWorks = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<artWork[]>("data/artwork.json");
       
    }

    public class artWork
    {
        public int artworkID { get; set; }
        public string? artworkName { get; set; }
        public string? artworkFilename { get; set; }
        public string? description { get; set; }
        public string? artworkMediumID { get; set; }
        public string? price { get; set; }
        public string? width { get; set; }
        public string? height { get; set; }
    }

}

and I have a for each like so
@foreach (var artWork in artWorks)
{

<div class="art-wrapper">
    <div class="img-thumb">
        <a href="img/artwork/@artWork.artworkFilename" ToolTip="@artWork.artworkName - By Trevor Bollen" title="@artWork.artworkName - By Trevor Bollen">
            <img src="img/artwork/@artWork.artworkFilename.Replace(".jpg", "_thumb.jpg")" title="@artWork.artworkName - By Trevor Bollen" alt="@artWork.artworkName - By Trevor Bollen" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="art-info">
        <h3>@artWork.artworkName</h3>
        <p><b>Medium:</b> @artWork.artworkMediumID </p>
        <p><b>Size:</b> @artWork.width x @artWork.height (cm) </p>
        <p><b>Price:</b> £@artWork.price</p>
    <p><a href="portfoliodetail/@artWork.artworkID"><img src="img/btn-detail-sml.jpg" Class="btnViewDetail" AlternateText="Click here to view artwork details" ToolTip="Click here to view artwork details" /></a></p>
    </div>
</div>


}

Which links through to the portfoliodetail page with Parameter. My question is, on this page how do I get the single record from my JSON using the ID passed through? So far I have the following but not sure how to filter or get by ID
@code {
private artWork? artWorks;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   
        artWorks = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<artWork>("data/artwork.json");
   
}

public class artWork
{
    public int artworkID { get; set; }
    public string? artworkName { get; set; }
    public string? artworkFilename { get; set; }
    public string? description { get; set; }
    public string? artworkMediumID { get; set; }
    public string? price { get; set; }
    public string? width { get; set; }
    public string? height { get; set; }
}

}

Sample of Data shown below.


Are we talking reading data from a static artwork.json?  Or is that really just for demo and you are really talking to an API?

no i plan to use a static json file

Here's a fairly simple example using a service to get and cache the Json data and provide methods to get a collection or a single object.
This example is based on getting this simple record:
public record CountryRecord(string Country, string Continent);

A Repository Service to get and cache the data:
public class CountryRepository
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private List<CountryRecord> _countries = new();
    private Task? _getDataTask;
    private object _lock = new();

    public CountryRepository(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async ValueTask<IEnumerable<CountryRecord>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        await GetData();
        return _countries;
    }

    public async ValueTask<CountryRecord?> GetItemAsync(string country)
    {
        await GetData();
        return _countries.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Country.Equals(country));
    }

    private Task GetData()
    {
        if (_getDataTask is not null)
            return _getDataTask;

        // ensures only one process can start the Task
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_getDataTask is null)
                _getDataTask = this.GetHttpDataAsync();
        }

        return _getDataTask;
    }

    private async Task GetHttpDataAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var countries = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<CountryRecord>>("https://localhost:7191/sample-data/countries.json");
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(countries, "Json file not found.");
        _countries = countries;
    }
}

And the registered service:
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CountryRepository>();

You can now inject the service into any page/component and either get the full collection by calling GetItemsAsync or a single item by calling GetItemAsync.

THanks for the feedback, got it working another way but will look to implement above approach

Would the public class CountryRepository be on the page or in its own controller?

Either.  I use a Presentation layer in all my apps, to handle all the data management and UI implementation specific code.  The CountryRepository would live there.  The page component code only handles UI specific logic: UI event handlers, button enable/disable code,....
